# Store Circle Data drawn on Google Map

Tags: laravel, google-maps, coordinates, geometry-surface

I am working in a Laravel application where Polygon Coordinates drawn on Google Map store in a column with data type polygon.

[image]

Later below code is used to search a Coordinate inside those polygons.

```
$point = new Point( $request->latitude, $request->longitude );
$zone  = RestaurantZones::contains( 'coordinates', $point )->pluck( 'id' );
```

Now I would like to store Circle Data drawn on Google Map and search a Coordinate inside that Circle in a similar way.

Comment: I am not understanding your question, what would the issue be? What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: Thanks @matiaslauriti. Actually I would like to store Circle center coordinate and radius in database. Later I would like to find a point is inside that circle.

Comment: And, I have to ask it again, what is the issue you are having? You are telling us what you want to achieve, but not what the issue is. What code have you try to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In a circle, you can store it by creating two fields latitude and longitude or as you have mentioned coordinates also here need to store the circle's radius to find out whether the coordinates are inside that circle or not. Let's demonstrate this.

**DRAW & STORE CIRCLE'S COORDINATES AND RADIUS**

```js
let map;
let drawingManager;
let circle;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });

  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE],
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: "#ffff00",
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1,
    },
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "circlecomplete", function (circleObject) {
    // Remove the previous circle if it exists
    if (circle) {
      circle.setMap(null);
    }

    // Set the new circle
    circle = circleObject;

    // Log coordinates and radius
    const center = circle.getCenter();
    const radius = circle.getRadius();
    console.log("Coordinates: " + center.toUrlValue());
    console.log("Radius: " + radius + " meters");

  // Send the data to the Laravel controller using AJAX
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your-route',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      center: center.toUrlValue(),
      radius: radius,
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response.message);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    },
  });

  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drawing Tools</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when you have stored coordinates in a spatial way can use this to find out whether a coordinate is inside the circle or not

```
$targetPoint = new Point($latitude, $longitude);
$zone = RestaurantZones::whereRaw(
        "ST_Distance(coordinates, ?) <= radius",
        [$targetPoint]
    )->first();

    if ($zone) {
        return 'Coordinate is inside a zone';
    }

    return 'Coordinate is outside all zones';
```

And if coordinates are in separated in lat and lng then may you use this

```
public function checkCoordinateInZone($latitude, $longitude)
{
    $targetPoint = ['lat' => $latitude, 'lng' => $longitude];
    
    $zones = RestaurantZones::all();
    
    foreach ($zones as $zone) {
        $circleCenter = $zone->coordinates;
        $circleRadius = $zone->radius;
        
        $distance = $this->calculateDistance($circleCenter, $targetPoint);
        
        if ($distance <= $circleRadius) {
            return 'Coordinate is inside a zone';
        }
    }
    
    return 'Coordinate is outside all zones';
}

private function calculateDistance($point1, $point2)
{
    $lat1 = deg2rad($point1->getLat());
    $lon1 = deg2rad($point1->getLng());
    $lat2 = deg2rad($point2['lat']);
    $lon2 = deg2rad($point2['lng']);

    // Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two coordinates
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlon = $lon2 - $lon1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlon / 2) * sin($dlon / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $distance = 6371000 * $c; // Radius of Earth in meters

    return $distance;
}
```

**May this help you Kindly read Google Map JS API to understand in a better way.**

Comment: Thanks @Md Mainul Islam vai. Can I use `contains()` method to find out a Coordinate is inside a Circle ?

Comment: **contains()** method can be used to check if a point or geometry is entirely contained within a polygon or another geometry. However, it may not directly apply to checking if a coordinate is inside a circle since a circle is not a polygon but rather a point with a radius.

If you want to check if a coordinate is inside a circular zone, you might need to use a combination of spatial functions and logic above mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Md Mainul Islam vai. How can I fetch spatial data using Laravel ? I would like to use like below.  ```
const mapItems = [
                @foreach($coordinates as $zone)
                    type: 'circle',
                    coords: {
 @php($coordinates = str_replace(['(', ')'], '', $zone->circle_coordinates))
 @php($parts = explode(',', $coordinates))
 lat: {{ floatval(trim($parts[0])) }},
 lng: {{ floatval(trim($parts[1])) }}
                    },
                    radius: {{ $zone->radius }},
                    key: {{ $loop->index }}
            ];
```